# Cakephp 3 - Database populate select option with custom class and custom attrib

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I hope I'm doing very well, I'm learning cakephp 3 and I'm stuck. I have problems adding a custom attribute to each selector option and a custom class as well.

What I have right now is this:

**Controller**

```
// Insercion datos EspMunicipios
    $this->loadModel('EspMunicipios');
    $camping = $this->EspMunicipios->CampingInfos->newEntity();

    // EspMunicipios
    $ResultMunicipio = $this->EspMunicipios->find('all',
                                        array(
                                            'fields'=>array('id','municipio','id_provincia'),
                                            'order' => ['EspMunicipios.municipio' => 'ASC']
                                            ));

    $row_options_municipios = array();
    $row_data_id_provincia = array();
    foreach($ResultMunicipio->toArray() as $key => $val){
        $row_options_municipios[$val['id']] = $val['municipio'];
    }

    $this->set('ResultMunicipio', $row_options_municipios);

    // Fin EspMunicipios
```

**View**

```
echo $this->Form->select('id_municipio',$ResultMunicipio);
```

***edit (add result):***

```
<option value="6537">Ababuj</option>
```

**And what I want to do is this (I've done this without the framework):**

```
<select class="form-control" id="municipio" name="municipio" disabled="disabled">

                <?php
                echo '<option value="0" selected="selected">Seleccione un municipio</option>';
                while ($line = $R_Municipios->fetch_row()) {
                    echo "<option class='hide' id='option_municipio' prov=".$line[2]." value=".$line[0].">";
                    echo $line[1];
                    echo "</option>";
                }

                // Liberar resultados
                $R_Municipios->free();
                ?>
            </select>
```

**Result**

```
<option class="hide" id='option_municipio' prov="3" value="6537" >Ababuj</option>
```

I would like to make a custom attribute "prov" or "data-prov", also assign the "hide" class to each option and custom id. I do this because all the results will be controlled by jquery, changing the hide class to show.

I would like to know how to add custom attributes and custom classes to each selector option, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I already found the solution sorry, here I post it to help someone.**

**Controller**

```
    // Insercion datos EspMunicipios
    $this->loadModel('EspMunicipios');
    $camping = $this->EspMunicipios->CampingInfos->newEntity();

    // EspMunicipios
    $ResultMunicipio = $this->EspMunicipios->find('all',
                                        array(
                                            'fields'=>array('id','municipio','id_provincia'),
                                            'order' => ['EspMunicipios.municipio' => 'ASC']
                                            )); //or whatever conditions you want

    $row_options_municipios = array();
    foreach($ResultMunicipio->toArray() as $key => $val){

        $row_options_municipios[$val['id']] = array('text' => $val['municipio'], 'value' => $val['id'], 'class' => 'hide', 'data-prov' => $val['id_provincia'], 'id' => 'option_municipio');
    }

    $this->set('ResultMunicipio', $row_options_municipios);

    // Fin EspMunicipios
```

**View**

```
echo $this->Form->input('id_municipio',array(
    'type' => 'select',
    'options' => $ResultMunicipio
    ));
```

**Result**

```
<option value="6537" class="hide" data-prov="44" id="option_municipio">Ababuj</option>
```